# Fixing a noisy I2C bus

Tags: arduino, i2c, noise, gyro

I'm trying to get an I2C bus working but there's a ton of noise and I don't really know what's causing it.  The circuit is pretty simple, an [ITG-3200](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11977) and an Arduino DUE.

Here is the problem:
[image: SCL (top) SDA (bottom)]

As you can see, there's a significant amount of undershoot on both lines.

[image]

Hard to see in this picture but theres a lot of weird stuff going on with the SDA line.  Also note faint the undershoot peaks on both signals

Comment: It looks pretty clean to me. Some of the ripple might be caused by the scope itself.

Comment: how are you connecting your scope probe to GND when you take these measurements too?

Comment: Ground is connected to the arduino by one of the probe ground leads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really hard to debug this from just the plots you presented but it looks to me like output is not terminated.  You appear to have reflection on your data lines. I can tell this because you are getting ringing on logic transitions.  Look up the suggested termination in the datasheets.

Comment: Termination on I2C?

Comment: Yes, the OP is using two boards.  http://www.i2c-bus.org/termination-versus-serial-resistance/

Comment: Do you think you could explain what you mean by I2C termination a bit?  I'm slightly confused here.  I understand how I2C is usually operated with a set of pull up resistors (which I have).

Comment: @pdel: Termination in general is the practice of *ending* a set of wires with a resistor that is equal to the characteristic impedance.  Basically, that makes it appear electrically as an infinite length of wire, thus no reflections.  In your case, it might be easiest to remove your single pullups from the middle of the wires and put a potentiometer at each end of each wire.  Do a lot of testing and tweaking until you minimize the weirdness, then replace the pots with fixed resistors of each measured value.  ~100-1kOhm log- or audio-taper pots should cover the expected range pretty well.

Comment: Note, however, that by doing this (actually just by using long wires), the effective pullup that the I2C driver sees initially is the lines' impedance, not the actual pullup.  Eventually, after all the reflections have died down, you'll see the actual pullup take over, but it's completely invisible until a round-trip speed-of-light delay from the driver to the resistor and back.  Welcome to transmission lines!  :-)

Comment: Thanks for all the info everyone.  These were not variables I was even considering.  Oh the joys of being a software guy in a hardware world.